# Creating Classes representing Polygons instead of storing in Arrays

Tags: java, class, draw

I have been given the task to improve a piece of code. The code is meant to draw different polygons. The initial code has a constructor which adds the names of polygons such as "triangle", "square" and "rectangle" to an ArrayList. Another ArrayList contains the centerpoints for each polygon. I have been hinted that creating a class for each polygon would improve the code as it hinders errors as early as in the compiling state, such as if the user would mistype a polygon name. I am pretty new to coding so I don't really know how that could be implemented practically. Could anyone give an example on how such a class would look like?

Comment: Use an enumeration.

Comment: I discussed that with my teacher but he preferred using classes

Answer (score 1):

You could create an `Enum` for the polygon types, like this:

```
public enum PolygonType{
    TRIANGLE, SQUARE, RECTANGLE, PENTAGON, HEXAGON
}
```

And create a class, that represents a single instance of a Polygon:

```
public class Polygon {
    private final PolygonType type;
    
    //Use whatever Point class you use now here
    private final Point2D center;

    public Polygon(PolygonType type, Point2D center) {
         this.type = type;
         this.center = center;
    }

    public PolygonType getType() {
         return type;
    }
    public Point2D getCenter() {
         return center;
    }
}
```

And then simple have a `List<Polygon>`

If you don't want to use an enum for the type, you can also just store the number of sides, or store the type as a String. I prefer using an `enum` because you can't use an incorrect value.

You could also give your enum additional information if you need it by adding fields and a constructor (constructor should be `private`), e.g. number of sides:

```java
public enum PolygonType {
     TRIANGLE(3), SQUARE(4), RECTANGLE(4);

     public final int sides;
     private PolygonType(int sides) {this.sides = sides;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `ShapeType` as a way of identifying shapes.

Then you could create an `abstract` class that represents a `Shape` and then extend it by creating various polygons and geometric shapes.

If all the shapes have a type, location (origin), and a size, you could create a shape of that type by processing the type through a `switch` statement.

---

## Demo

The example below generates 10-50 random shapes of random colors with a size of 5%-10% of the canvas width and places them within 1/3rd max distance of the center of the canvas.

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class App implements Runnable {
    private enum ShapeType {
        CIRCLE, HEXAGON, PENTAGON, RECTANGLE, SQUARE, TRIANGLE;
    }

    private static abstract class Shape {
        private ShapeType type;
        private Point2D origin;
        private Color color;
        protected boolean dirty;
        protected Map<String, Object> attributes;

        public ShapeType getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public Point2D getOrigin() {
            return origin;
        }

        public void setOrigin(Point2D origin) {
            this.origin = origin;
            this.dirty = true;
        }

        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        public void setColor(Color color) {
            this.color = color;
            this.dirty = true;
        }

        public Map<String, Object> getAttributes() {
            return attributes;
        }

        public Shape(ShapeType type, Point2D origin, Color color) {
            this.type = type;
            this.origin = origin;
            this.color = color;
            this.attributes = new HashMap<>();
            this.dirty = true;
        }

        protected void attr(String attribute, Object value) {
            this.attributes.put(attribute, value);
        }

        protected Object attr(String attribute) {
            return this.attributes.get(attribute);
        }

        protected void recalculate() {
            syncAttributes();
            this.dirty = false;
        }

        protected void syncAttributes() {
            int rgb = (this.getColor().getRGB() << 8) >>> 8;

            attr("color", String.format("#%06X", rgb));
            attr("x", getOrigin().getX());
            attr("y", getOrigin().getY());
        }

        public abstract void draw(Graphics2D g2d);
    }

    private static class Rectangle extends Shape {
        private int x;
        private int y;
        private int width;
        private int height;

        public int getWidth() {
            return width;
        }

        public void setWidth(int width) {
            this.width = width;
            this.dirty = true;
        }

        public int getHeight() {
            return height;
        }

        public void setHeight(int height) {
            this.height = height;
            this.dirty = true;
        }

        public Rectangle(Point2D origin, Color color, int width, int height) {
            super(ShapeType.RECTANGLE, origin, color);
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
        }

        @Override
        protected void syncAttributes() {
            super.syncAttributes();

            attr("width", this.getWidth());
            attr("height", this.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void recalculate() {
            this.x = (int) getOrigin().getX() - this.width / 2;
            this.y = (int) getOrigin().getY() - this.height / 2;

            super.recalculate();
        }

        @Override
        public void draw(Graphics2D g2d) {
            g2d.setColor(this.getColor());
            g2d.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
    }

    private static class Square extends Shape {
        private Rectangle rectangle;

        @Override
        public Color getColor() {
            return rectangle.getColor();
        }

        @Override
        public void setColor(Color color) {
            rectangle.setColor(color);
            this.dirty = true;
        }

        @Override
        public Point2D getOrigin() {
            return rectangle.getOrigin();
        }

        @Override
        public void setOrigin(Point2D origin) {
            rectangle.setOrigin(origin);
            this.dirty = true;
        }

        public int getSize() {
            return rectangle.getWidth();
        }

        public void setSize(int size) {
            rectangle.setWidth(size);
            rectangle.setHeight(size);
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, Object> getAttributes() {
            return rectangle.getAttributes();
        }

        public Square(Point2D origin, Color color, int size) {
            super(ShapeType.SQUARE, null, null);
            this.rectangle = new Rectangle(origin, color, size, size);
        }

        @Override
        protected void syncAttributes() {
            super.syncAttributes();

            attr("size", this.getSize());
        }

        @Override
        protected void recalculate() {
            this.rectangle.recalculate();
        }

        @Override
        public void draw(Graphics2D g2d) {
            this.rectangle.draw(g2d);
        }
    }

    private static abstract class Polygon2D extends Shape {
        private int sides;
        private int radius;
        private Polygon polygon;

        public int getRadius() {
            return radius;
        }

        public void setRadius(int radius) {
            this.radius = radius;
            this.dirty = true;
        }

        public Polygon2D(ShapeType type, int sides, Point2D origin, Color color, int radius) {
            super(type, origin, color);
            this.sides = sides;
            this.radius = radius;
            this.polygon = new Polygon();
        }

        @Override
        protected void syncAttributes() {
            super.syncAttributes();

            List<Point2D> points = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < this.polygon.npoints; i++) {
                points.add(new Point2D.Float(this.polygon.xpoints[i], this.polygon.ypoints[i]));
            }

            this.attr("radius", this.getRadius());
            this.attr("points", points);
        }

        @Override
        public void recalculate() {
            this.polygon.reset();

            double angle = Math.PI * 2 / this.sides;
            double start = -Math.PI / 2;

            for (int i = 0; i < this.sides; i++) {
                double x = getOrigin().getX() + this.radius * Math.cos(start + i * angle);
                double y = getOrigin().getY() + this.radius * Math.sin(start + i * angle);

                this.polygon.addPoint((int) x, (int) y);
            }

            super.recalculate();
        }

        @Override
        public void draw(Graphics2D g2d) {
            g2d.setColor(this.getColor());
            g2d.fillPolygon(this.polygon);
        }
    }

    private static class Triangle extends Polygon2D {
        public Triangle(Point2D origin, Color color, int radius) {
            super(ShapeType.TRIANGLE, 3, origin, color, radius);
        }
    }

    private static class Pentagon extends Polygon2D {
        public Pentagon(Point2D origin, Color color, int radius) {
            super(ShapeType.PENTAGON, 5, origin, color, radius);
        }
    }

    private static class Hexagon extends Polygon2D {
        public Hexagon(Point2D origin, Color color, int radius) {
            super(ShapeType.HEXAGON, 6, origin, color, radius);
        }
    }

    private static class Circle extends Shape {
        private int radius;
        private int x;
        private int y;
        private int width;
        private int height;

        public Circle(Point2D origin, Color color, int radius) {
            super(ShapeType.CIRCLE, origin, color);
            this.radius = radius;
        }

        public int getRadius() {
            return radius;
        }

        public void setRadius(int radius) {
            this.radius = radius;
            this.dirty = true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void syncAttributes() {
            super.syncAttributes();

            attr("radius", this.getRadius());
        }

        @Override
        protected void recalculate() {
            this.x = (int) (this.getOrigin().getX() - this.getRadius());
            this.y = (int) (this.getOrigin().getY() - this.getRadius());
            this.width = this.getRadius() * 2;
            this.height = this.width;

            super.recalculate();
        }

        @Override
        public void draw(Graphics2D g2d) {
            g2d.setColor(this.getColor());
            g2d.fillOval(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
    }

    private static class Canvas extends JPanel {
        private List<Shape> shapes;

        public Canvas() {
            super();

            this.shapes = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        public void addShape(Shape shape) {
            this.shapes.add(shape);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            g.setColor(new Color(0x111111));
            g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            for (Shape shape : this.shapes) {
                if (shape.dirty) {
                    shape.recalculate();
                }
                shape.draw(g2d);
                System.out.printf("Drawing %s %s%n", shape.getType(), JsonUtil.toJson(shape.getAttributes()));
            }
        }
    }

    private static class RandomUtil {
        private static final Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

        public static int randRange(int min, int max) {
            return rand.nextInt(max + 1 - min) + min;
        }

        public static float randFloat() {
            return rand.nextFloat();
        }

        public static <T> T randItem(T[] arr) {
            return arr[rand.nextInt(arr.length)];
        }
    }

    private static class JsonUtil {
        public static String toJson(Map<String, Object> map) {
            return String.format("{%s}", map.entrySet().stream()
                    .map(entry -> formatEntry(entry))
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
        }

        private static String formatValue(Object rawValue) {
            String value = String.valueOf(rawValue);

            if (rawValue instanceof String) {
                value = String.format("\"%s\"", value);
            } else if (rawValue instanceof List) {
                value = String.format("[%s]", ((List) rawValue).stream()
                        .map(val -> formatValue(val))
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
            } else if (rawValue instanceof Point2D) {
                Point2D point = (Point2D) rawValue;
                value = String.format("{\"x\":%.2f,\"y\":%.2f}", point.getX(), point.getY());
            }

            return value;
        }

        private static String formatEntry(Map.Entry entry) {
            return String.format("\"%s\":%s", entry.getKey(), formatValue(entry.getValue()));
        }
    }

    private static class ShapeUtil {
        public static Shape randomShape(Dimension bounds) {
            ShapeType type = RandomUtil.randItem(ShapeType.values());
            Color color = Color.getHSBColor(RandomUtil.randFloat(), 0.667f, 1.0f);
            int centerX = bounds.width / 2;
            int centerY = bounds.height / 2;
            int offX = bounds.width / 3;
            int offY = bounds.height / 3;
            int size = RandomUtil.randRange(bounds.width / 20, bounds.width / 10);
            int x = RandomUtil.randRange(centerX - offX, centerX + offX);
            int y = RandomUtil.randRange(centerY - offY, centerY + offY);
            Point2D origin = new Point2D.Float(x, y);

            return createShape(type, origin, color, size);
        }

        public static Shape createShape(ShapeType type, Point2D origin, Color color, int size) {
            switch (type) {
                case CIRCLE:
                    return new Circle(origin, color, size / 2);
                case HEXAGON:
                    return new Hexagon(origin, color, size / 2);
                case PENTAGON:
                    return new Pentagon(origin, color, size / 2);
                case RECTANGLE:
                case SQUARE:
                    return new Square(origin, color, size);
                case TRIANGLE:
                    return new Triangle(origin, color, size);
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
    }

    private String name;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private JFrame frame;

    public App(String name, int width, int height) {
        this.name = name;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    protected void initialize() {
        this.frame = new JFrame(this.name);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        Dimension bounds = new Dimension(this.width, this.height);
        int shapeCount = RandomUtil.randRange(10, 50);

        canvas.setPreferredSize(bounds);

        for (int i = 0; i < shapeCount; i++) {
            canvas.addShape(ShapeUtil.randomShape(bounds));
        }

        this.frame.setContentPane(canvas);
    }

    protected void finalize() {
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        initialize();
        finalize();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       try {
           SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new App("Random Shapes", 400, 300));
       } catch (InvocationTargetException | InterruptedException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: IMO this is an excellent solution, but maybe a bit to complex for what OP needs or wants.
But I don't really understand why you have an attributeMap and store the data in fields, this seems to be redundant and offers no benefit, except if string-based attribute lookup was needed.

Comment: @AlexanderDaum it was for logging.